# Show web operating steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm looking for a 'best-way' to show to a web-site visitor the operating steps of the site.

I have in mind some examples I have seen in programs like Adobe Lightroom after first-time installation, or first visit to some web-sites (which now I can't remember!). This is, highlighting a part of the visible web (i.e a button, a panel, a link...) by bluring or darkening the rest of the page, with a bubble-text pointing to it with a short description "Use this design panel to adjust your picture settings. Next..." for each of the parts to be remarked.

After some unsuccessfull google searching, I don't know where to start. How this kind of tools are named?

**My question**: Does anyone can give me a hint or an example, so that I can do my own product investigation about this kind of tools?

Sorry for the low concretion of the question.

Comment: You're asking for an opinion and a software recommendation, both of which are off topic requests for SO.

Comment: My question may deserve downvotes for being off-topic (sorry for it, I didn't remember about this restriction), but not the answer below. The concept I was looking for is 'Web Tour' and @mayersdesign lead me to it. Great!. Now I can do my own Googling and further porduct investigation.

Comment: I will reword the question so that I'm not asking for opinion or software recommendation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used [introjs](http://introjs.com/) for this once, and it worked well for me so I can recommend it. Here's [fairly recent list](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-tour-instructional-plugins/) of ten possibilities for "web-tours".

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Just so people know I don't agree with the rigidity of the opinion/recommendation ban. @MarcM above has a reasonable rep, has helped lots of other people, and he's obviously a professional seeking a bit of guidance from fellow professionals about what's worked for them. I don't see that as a bad thing. Downvote away.

Comment: Thanks for your commitment @mayersdesign, you helped me a lot! The concept 'Web Tour' is what I was looking for, and your answer yield me to it.
My question may deserve downvotes for being off-topic, but not your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes not knowing the "terminology" you need to search for is often a stumbling block, so I am glad I could help :)